# ASP.NET MVC Action Parameter Stack<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stack, action

I want to use a C# Stack as argument to an MVC action method.

My question is how should construct the query string such that the model binder correctly converts it into an object of Stack?

I have already tried sending it as `StackParam[0]="first"&StackParam[1]="second"` where `StackParam` is the name of the method argument. However, this approach didn't work.

Is it really possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Declare the action method argument as an array, and then convert that to a stack as the first step in the method.
2. Create a custom model binder to build the stack object to be passed into the action method.
3. Create a custom action filter attribute to build the stack object and pass it to the action method via the `filterContext.ActionParameters` collection.